# In Node.js I m using console.log which is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I used console.log to display a port number but it not working.It displaying string but when i use this with value it not displaying.

```
const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');
const socketio = require('socket.io');

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketio(server);

server.listen(PORT,()=>{
    return console.log('server has started on port ${PORT}');
});
```

I m getting Following:
Output:server has started on port ${PORT}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using it wrong. You must use backticks - ` and not quotes - '

So the correct format is -

```
server.listen(PORT,()=>{
    return console.log(`server has started on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

- **Quotes ('')** will just output whatever is given inside them.
- However, **Backticks(``)** will evaluate the expression inside `${}`
  and then output the evaluated value.

Hope this solves your issue !

Answer (score 0):

Wrong quotes

Use ``

```
console.log(`server has started on port ${PORT}`);
```